# SDL2 IMG_Load "unsupported image format" error message?

Tags: sdl-2, dynamic-linking, ldd, sdl-image

I'm trying to load a png image. libsdl2-dev and libsdl2-image-dev packages have been installed and I'm including SDL2/SDL_image.h. IMG_Init is working without error, but IMG_Load errors.

On my desktop PC (Ubuntu) it works (loads png into SDL_Surface), but it looks like my laptop (also Ubuntu) is not linking the required png library.

ldd (Desktop) libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007ff58db3c000)

ldd (laptop) No libpng lib

Even though both these machines have this library in the same location.

How can I figure out why it is not getting linked?

**Edit:** IMAGE_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG) is causing error "PNG Images are not supported"

Comment: PNG support can be disabled or be loaded dynamically at runtime (this is configured when SDL_image compiles). What flags do you pass to `IMG_Init`? Is there an error message in `SDL_GetError` after that?

Comment: Ahhh bad error check from me, IMG_Init is in fact giving "PNG Images are not supported" errors on my laptop (Desktop INIT does not give these errors). I'm using IMG_INIT_PNG flag.

Answer (score 0):

After removing libpng, libsdl2-dev, and libsdl2-image-dev I was able to re-install them and it works.